# Wrong sizes or offsets during animation

Tags: codenameone

As always when before trying to use features I am not familiar with I wrote a little Form descendant class in order to understand `com.codename1.ui.Container.replace(Component, Component, Transition)`.

One thing that is obvious when playing with my Form is that during the animation the components have different sizes and / or offsets as opposed to when they are not animated. I am sure that is not intended, is it?

The other thing I've discovered is that the command instance I added to the toolbar remains executable even if its `enabled` property is set to `false`. What should be to be expected here?

See the code:

```
public class FormReplaceComponent extends Form {
    private Component componentActual; 
    private Command commandReplace;

    public FormReplaceComponent() {
        setTitle("FormReplaceComponent");
        setScrollable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        FloatingActionButton badge = FloatingActionButton.createBadge("123");
        contentPane.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, badge);
        componentActual = badge;
        SpanLabel spanLabel = new SpanLabel(
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        CommonTransitions commonTransitions = CommonTransitions.createFade(800);
        Transition transitionWrapper = new Transition() {
            @Override
            public void initTransition() {
                commandReplace.setEnabled(false);
                commonTransitions.init(getSource(), getDestination());
                commonTransitions.initTransition();
            }
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
                commonTransitions.paint(aGraphics);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean animate() {
                return commonTransitions.animate();
            }
            @Override
            public void cleanup() {
                commonTransitions.cleanup();
                commandReplace.setEnabled(true);
                super.cleanup();
            }
        };
        commandReplace = new Command("Replace") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) {
                if (componentActual == badge) {
                    contentPane.replace(badge, spanLabel, transitionWrapper);
                    componentActual = spanLabel;
                } else {
                    contentPane.replace(spanLabel, badge, transitionWrapper);
                    componentActual = badge;
                }
            }
        };
        getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(commandReplace);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'replace' needs components of similar size otherwise you will see a skip due to the nature of the functionality. We usually use `Component.setSameSize()` on them.

I don't think the transition decorator you used is right but it's hard to tell.

Enabled will only apply before adding the command. Otherwise a command would need to track all its components and this could lead to a leak. You can use `findCommandComponent` & set enabled on that.

Comment: Using `com.codename1.ui.Toolbar.findCommandComponent(Command)` for updating the `enabled` attribute works well, thank You.

But even if `com.codename1.ui.Component.setSameSize(Component...)` is used, which shouldn't be neccessary anyway because the components are `com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout.CENTER`, the Transition paints the components visibly different. This happens in the simulator and on my iPhone 5S as well.

Comment: The `SpanLabel` apparently moves down and right during animation. The badge, a `FloatingActionButton`, apparently grows. Is this because the components are painted into images and this is different from painting directly?

Comment: That's possible. Is it only with Fade or does it happen with other transitions? Does it happen when you use the transition directly?

Comment: Yes, it happens with other transitions, too. But with a fade transition it catches the eye. Directly - You mean without my little `transitionWrapper`? Yes.

Comment: Is this specific to the components used? E.g. if you use a component other than the badge (just regular label) does it work better?

Comment: Now, that is really weird: If the `SpanLabel` in my example code is replaced by 'Label' the animation works without the glitches. I don't understand a thing.

Comment: The SpanLabel is a problematic component as it's based on text area which means it needs to calculate line breaks and reflows. That means it's very sensitive to available space and will change depending on that. It also means it performs slower... We suggest using it only when you really need it.